# Reading a registry key in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I have developed an application and installed it on a client computer. In my application I need to get its installation path. My application has a registry entry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\[AppPath]
```

How can I read `AppPath` using C#?

Comment: Using Microsoft's terminology, in your question, `MyApplication` is a *Key* and `AppPath` is a *Value*. What you are asking is how to get the *data* associated with `AppPath`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C

**Updated:**

You can use `RegistryKey` class under `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.

Some important functions of `RegistryKey` are as follows:

```
GetValue       //to get value of a key
SetValue       //to set value to a key
DeleteValue    //to delete value of a key
OpenSubKey     //to read value of a subkey (read-only)
CreateSubKey   //to create new or edit value to a subkey
DeleteSubKey   //to delete a subkey
GetValueKind   //to retrieve the datatype of registry key
```

Comment: Use this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C) instead.

Answer (score 119):

You're looking for the cunningly named [`Registry.GetValue` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx).

Comment: Who would have known :P

Answer (score 85):

```
string InstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\AppPath", "Installed", null);    
if (InstallPath != null)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

That code should get your value. You'll need to be

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

for that to work though.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following to get where the registry thinks it's installed:

```
(string)Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\MyApplication\AppPath",
   "Installed", null);
```

Or you can use the following to find out where the application is actually being launched from:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
```

The latter is more reliable than the former if you're trying to use the `.exe` location as a relative path to find related files.  The user could easily move things around after the install and still have the app work fine because .NET apps aren't so dependent upon the registry.

Using `StartupPath`, you could even do something clever like have your app update the registry entries at run time instead of crashing miserably due to missing/wrong/corrupted entries.

And be sure to look at the app settings functionality as storage for values rather than the registry (`Properties.Settings.Default.mySettingEtc`).  You can read/write settings for the app and/or the user levels that get saved as simple `MyApp.exe.config` files in standard locations.  A nice blast from the past (good old Win 3.1/DOS days) to have the application install/delete be a simple copy/delete of a folder structure or two rather than some convoluted, arcane install/uninstall routine that leaves all kinds of garbage in the registry and sprinkled all over the hard drive.

Comment: In the same vein, these can be useful in the effort: `Environment.CommandLine` and `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: This also works: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Comment: Using System.Reflection: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location will get the full path, then System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName to pick off the parent folder.

Answer (score 8):

If you want it casted to a specific type you can use this method. Most non primitive types won't by default support direct casting so you will have to handle those accordingly.

```
  public T GetValue<T>(string registryKeyPath, string value, T defaultValue = default(T))
  {
    T retVal = default(T);

      retVal = (T)Registry.GetValue(registryKeyPath, value, defaultValue);

      return retVal;
  }
```

Comment: This works nicely. Example usage: `int loopback = GetValue<int>(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa", @"DisableLoopbackCheck", -1);`.

Answer (score 2):

using Microsoft.Win32;

```
  string chkRegVC = "NO";
   private void checkReg_vcredist() {

        string regKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey uninstallKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKey))
        {
            if (uninstallKey != null)
            {
                string[] productKeys = uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                foreach (var keyName in productKeys)
                {

                    if (keyName == "{196BB40D-1578-3D01-B289-BEFC77A11A1E}" ||//Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) 
                        keyName == "{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}" ||//Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) 
                        keyName == "{C1A35166-4301-38E9-BA67-02823AD72A1B}" ||//Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (ia64) 
                        keyName == "{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}" ||//Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) 
                        keyName == "{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}" ||//Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) 
                        keyName == "{88C73C1C-2DE5-3B01-AFB8-B46EF4AB41CD}"   //Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (ia64) 
                        ) { chkRegVC = "OK"; break; }
                    else { chkRegVC = "NO"; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```